# Angular 8 change value on select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 and I have a dropdown that looks like this:

Countries:

- US - United States UK
- UK - United Kingdom
- HK - Hong Kong

When I select a value from the dropdown, I want to show only the first two characters. For example, if I select US - United States, I only want to show "US". In my "option" I'm displaying the data using `*ngFor`.

Comment: Do you use angular material/components?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying different ways to accomplish this, but I need someone to show me the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```html
<select name="countries">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country.split(' ').map(x=>x[0]).join('')}}</option>
</select>
```

but embedding logic in a template like that isn't great, so you're probably better off defining a method on the component to get the letters for you:

```js
public countryLabel(country: string): string {
    return country.split(' ').map(x=>x[0]).join('');
}
```

and then use it like:

```html
<select name="countries">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{countryLabel(country)}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat-select-trigger` as documentation says: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Countries</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="country" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{ getLabelForCountry() }}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This code is just an illustration of how the template would be. Since you didn't posted more details about your code (if you are using reactivate forms or not, data structure), you will need to adapt it to your reality. But that's the way to follow